# Intellij IDEA | Failed to package AIR application ios

Tags: java, ios, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, air

When I create build **.ipa** or assembly test device on iOS, I get this error:

[image]

[image]

How to solve this problem?

*OS: Windows 7 x64*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is not absurd, but it turns out it was necessary to install **Java 1.6+ 32-bits**, rather than 64-bits. 
It is 32-bits, although Windows 64-bits.

That's all.